# "Error" reference notation in Velocity

Tags: null, velocity

Velocity has two forms of references: `$foo` (the default notation) and `$!foo` (the "quiet" notation). If `'foo'` can't be resolved in the context, in the first case you'll just get $foo rendered in the output. In the latter case, it will render as an empty string.

Is there a similarly terse syntax for a third case, one which simply throws an NPE when `'foo'` can't be found? We have something like `$a.b.c` which we'd like to fail if `'a'` or `'b'` are missing, but hopefully without gratuitous `#if($a && $a.b && $a.b.c) ... #end` checks cluttering the template all over the place.

Alternatively, can the behavior of `$!` be modified, or can a new term (like `$~`) be introduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Strict Reference Mode](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Strict_Reference_Mode), introduced in Velocity 1.6, does something like what you want. Instead of having a third reference form, it changes the way `$var` works so that if there's a `null` encountered while processing the variable (and possible chained method calls), an exception is thrown instead of printing the literal input syntax back.

It is possible to put your own `$~` syntax in Velocity (anything is possible given enough time and effort), but not easily. You'd have to heavily patch the source code, from the grammar definition to how references are handled.